# Resizing for jQuery Parallax

Tags: jquery, resize, parallax, jquery-resizable

Trying to create a site with jQuery parallax that resizes correctly when shrinking or enlarging the window. I am aiming for the same type of functionality when you drag the corners/resize on the flash site below.

http://www.intersectionpartners.com/

Any advice on how to do this with jQuery?

Comment: You example site is not working correctly.. It only resizes the content on vertical changes and not on horizontal changes.. Besides that the plugin provides an example for resizable windows at http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/target.html